# Cast receiver on local IIS yields ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have a custom receiver app (I tried [this one](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideoPlayer/blob/master/receiver.html) as well) which is hosted locally on my `IIS 10 Express` server. I have verified that I can see my web page from other devices on my local network.

When I show the receiver app page on my local Chrome browser, I see the following in the Debug output:

```
cast_receiver.js:53
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc' failed:
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**Is this an error or is it showing just because I'm running the page on a non-Chromecast device?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you cannot run a receiver app in your desktop chrome browser; it needs to run on a Cast device; a Cast device is more than just a chrome browser.

Comment: Just to test my app. I required chromecast ?